# Filter list of objects in RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2, rx-android

I am trying to filter the list on the basis of it's property. For example, Sensors class has a property `isActive` and I want to get all the objects with `isActive` as `true` but I am unable to do it. I tried different ways but I didn't find the solution. Can someone help me to do it?

Here is my code:

```
mCompositeDisposable.add(
    fcService.getStationList()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .flatMap(stations -> {
        return fcService.getSensorList(stations.get(0).getName().getOriginal());}
    ).subscribe(this::handleSensors, this::handleError));
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First, you need to emit each item from the `List` individually. That can be achieved using [`flatMap()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#flatMap-io.reactivex.functions.Function-) and [`Observable.fromIterable(Iterable)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#fromIterable-java.lang.Iterable-).

Then apply [`filter()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#filter-io.reactivex.functions.Predicate-) operator. Lastly, collect all of those items into list again using [`toList()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#toList--).

```
    service.getSensorsList()
              .flatMap(Observable::fromIterable)
              .filter(sensor -> sensor.isActive())
              .toList()
              .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
              .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
              .subscribe(this::handleSensors, this::handleError)
```

Comment: Thanks @azizbekian. This solution worked but not exactly the way I want. It is returning one sensor at a time in `handleSensors` and not a `List<Sensor>`. This mean, let's say there are 100 sensors returned and only 15 sensors have `isActive == true` then `handleSensors` is getting called 15 times. Can I just return the `List<Sensor>` so that `handleSensors` is called only once?

Comment: Thanks it worked. I missed `.toList()` in my previous try.

Answer (score 22):

**Kotlin** users can use a more simple approach like below.

```
fcService.getStationList()
    .map(it.filter {sensor -> sensor.isActive()})
```

It is possible because Kotlin has so many list operators itself, so for the filtering part you don't have to use rx. `it.filter {sensor -> sensor.isActive()}` is pure Kotlin code.

Comment: The questions asks for a solution using RxJava, not Kotlin.

Comment: @azizbekian I know! I'm just offering an alternative solution to those who use Kotlin.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to delete the values of a list based on Rejex and finally return a **Observable list model**

```
fun getList(): Observable<List<Destination>> {
    return appDataBase.dao().getAllList().flatMap {
        Observable.fromIterable(it).filter { destination ->
            destination.number.matches(regex = "[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\\s\\./0-9]*\$".toRegex())
        }.toList().toObservable()
    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

}
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me.

```
import io.reactivex.Observable
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable
import io.reactivex.observers.DisposableSingleObserver
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers
import java.util.*
import javax.inject.Inject
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList

    class MainPresenter {
    ....

    var disposable: Disposable? = null
    fun filterArticlesList(text: String?) {
            if (text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
                LogDebug.d("filterArticlesList", "cleared text")
                staticArticlesListFiltered = staticArticlesList
                getView()?.onFilterListSuccess(staticArticlesListFiltered)
            } else {
                val locale = Locale.getDefault()
                val textLower = text.toLowerCase(locale)
                disposable?.dispose()
                disposable = (Observable.fromIterable(staticArticlesList)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .filter { article -> article.title.toLowerCase(locale).contains(textLower) }
                    .toList()
                    .subscribeWith(FilterObserver(this@MainPresenter)))
            }
        }

    }
    class FilterObserver(private val presenter: MainPresenter) :
        DisposableSingleObserver<List<Article>>() {
        override fun onSuccess(t: List<Article>) {
            LogDebug.d("FilterObserver", "onSuccess")
        }

        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
            LogDebug.e("FilterObserver", "onError", e)
        }

    }
```