# How to filter a list using RxJava and group all matched elements

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I have a very large list and want to perform a simple `Filter` operation on it in a background thread, and then get the list of results that match the filter criteria at the end of the operation.

I'm still new at RxJava so I'm struggling to get this to work. What I have is the following (`largeList` is an `ArrayList` filled with `Item`):

```
    Observable
            .fromIterable(largeList)
            .filter { it.name.contains(query) }
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe { ... }
```

When I `subscribe`, I get back a single `Item` instead of a complete list of all items which passed the filter. How can I create a sublist of all matched results?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter list of objects in RxJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48685226/filter-list-of-objects-in-rxjava)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the toList() operator.
[image: toList working]

For a given Observable, it will collect incoming emissions into a List and then push that entire List as a single emission (through Single>).

```
 Observable
                .fromIterable(largeList)
                .filter { it.name.contains(query) }
                .toList() 
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe { ... }
```

Also, you can optionally specify an integer argument to serve as the capacityHint, and that will optimize the initialization of ArrayList to expect roughly that number of items:

```
  Observable
                    .fromIterable(largeList)
                    .filter { it.name.contains(query) }
                    .toList(capacityHint)
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe { ... }
```